# Can someone describe this CSS selectors please?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Please give me a explanation on what this selectors do please:

1. `img[alt$="a"]`
2. `li:odd p`
3. `p:nth-child(2n +1)`
4. `input:not([required])`
5. `ul li.selected p::before`

Comment: Is this homework? (Not trying to be rude, but it looks a lot like a copy paste from a question sheet)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors should be helping to start with :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest you search the Internet for these selectors before asking here. StackOverflow isn't a place for people to answer questions you haven't tried to research on your own. If you have done your own research and come up short, share your work along side your question.

Comment: I researched and found nothing on these ones, i find them very hard to understand

Comment: Glad to hear you did! What searches did you try? Edit them into the question. Doing so will help your question be received better here. (I'll remove my downvote if you edit your search terms in.) Also, try searching for tutorials and explanations on basic CSS selectors and try those selectors out at places like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). The farther you can go on your own, and the more specific you can make your questions, the better.

Comment: li:odd p is not a valid CSS selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try googling a bit before you resolve to asking this kind of questions.

```
img[alt$="a"]
```

Selects every `<img>` element with `alt` attribute value ending with `a`

```
li:odd p
```

Selects every paragraph `<p>` under every odd `<li>`

```
p:nth-child(2n +1)
```

Selects every `(2n+1)th` paragraph

```
input:not([required])
```

Selects every `<input>` element that's not required

```
ul li.selected p::before
```

Inserts something before the content of each `<p>` element under every `<li>` element with `selected` class